# Display: flex and new line for captions - what is the proper way?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In a project that I recently joined I have code structure like this:

```
// HTML / React
<Root>
  <Content>
    <ContentText>Some text</ContentText>
    <Caption>10 steps</Caption>
    <Date>March 22nd</Date>
  </Content>
</Root>

// CSS
.root {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 72px;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: var(--radius-medium)px;
  border: 1px solid var(--color-gray2);
  padding: 12px 4px;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  padding: 0 8px;
}
```

Now I need to create that two elements:

```
`<Caption>10 steps</Caption>`
```

and

```
`<Date>March 22nd</Date>`
```

To achieve view like this:
[View blueprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycrMl.png)

**My question is:**

what css code should I use in caption and date class to achieve this effect that you can see on the picture.

And most important thing - I want to do it with respecting previous project code that was written by more experienced developers than I am!

I want my code to fit well.

Sorry for noob question - but this is my first day at work -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `flex-wrap: wrap`to the `Container` and then make the `ContentText` be 100% wide, using i.e. `width: 100%;`

The above will make the `ContentText` take full width and the `flex-wrap: wrap` will allow the items to wrap, hence pushing the `Caption` and `Date` to a new line.

Stack snippet

```css
Root {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 72px;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: var(--radius-medium)px;
  border: 1px solid var(--color-gray2);
  padding: 12px 4px;
}

Content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;             /*  added property  */
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  padding: 0 8px;
} 

ContentText {                  /*  added rule  */
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<Root>
  <Content>
    <ContentText>Some text</ContentText>
    <Caption>10 steps</Caption>
    <Date>March 22nd</Date>
  </Content>
</Root>
```